# Passing NSString argument to SOAP WS yields "Illegal processing instruction target ("xml")"

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, soap, glassfish

I am invoking the WS using SudzC generated code:

```
[service createPendingSalesOrders:self action:@selector(handler:) arg0: 
 @"<?xml version='1.0'"
 " encoding='utf-8'?>"
 "<root>test</root>"];
```

The soap request is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope   
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:com="http://com/">
      <soapenv:Body>
           <com:createPendingSalesOrders>
                <arg0>"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><root>test</root>"
                </arg0>          
           </com:createPendingSalesOrders>
      </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am receiving:

`[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.`

from my WS running on glassfish.

The WS works with other XML strings that seem to contain the same PI.

Thanks for any insight,
Dane

Comment: please look at this also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448791/how-can-i-access-this-message-in-fault-sequence-in-wso2-esb

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on wrapping xml into xml, put the contents into CDATA section, so the parser would process it as a string.