# How can I access this message in fault sequence in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: xpath, xquery, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

How can I access this error text which is from wso2dss side standard error in WSO2 ESB fault sequence ERROR_CODE?

I am getting properly but this ERROR_MESSAGE giving NUll. How can I do this?

This is WSO2DSS standard ERROR message:

```
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Code>
      <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Receiver</soapenv:Value>
   </soapenv:Code>
   <soapenv:Reason>
      <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">The emp_DataService service, which is not valid, does not belong to the emp_DataService service group.</soapenv:Text>
   </soapenv:Reason>
   <soapenv:Detail/>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

I want to access the code of error as well as error text. Why? Because I need send a mail to backend department which will help them to trace a error as soon as possible.

How can I do this in WSO2ESB?

I want this two nodes to show:

1. ```
   <soapenv:Code>
             <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Receiver</soapenv:Value>
          </soapenv:Code>
   ```
  2.

> ```
>  &ltsoapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US"
>  xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">The emp_DataService
>  service, which is not valid, does not belong to the emp_DataService
>  service group. &lt/soapenv:Text>
> ```

How can I access this? Anyone know this?

Comment: i tried this //Text/text() but its not working

Comment: please see this one also if u want more clarification ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402606/how-to-know-error-message-in-wso2dss

Comment: Can you try this method. It will allow you to receive this Soap Fault in the WSO2 ESB's fault sequence.
http://maharachchi.blogspot.com/2012/09/now-you-can-send-soapfaults-to-fault.html

Answer (score 1):

In ESB as default the SOAP error is not recognized. It just passes it as a basic soap Message.
In order to identify it as a SOAP_FAULT you should set the property

```
<property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true">
```

After wards it will trigger fault sequence for the incoming SOAP_FAULT.
So you have to declare coming message is a SOAP_FAULT so you hace to say it is a SOAP_FAULT and force it to error sequence. This is explained in [1] a blog past my Amila.

For the second part of the question you can use payload Factory transformation.
You can use following sequence.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ErrorTransformSequence">
   <log level="full">
      <property name="SEQUENCE" value="----------------DSS FAULT------------------"/>
   </log>
   <payloadFactory>
      <format>
         <m:errorMessage xmlns:m="http://dss.error">                  
            <m:error>                     
               <m:message>$1</m:message>                  
            </m:error>
         </m:errorMessage>
      </format>
      <args>
         <arg value="/soapenv:Fault/soapenv:Reason/soapenv:Text/text()"/>
      </args>
   </payloadFactory>
   <header name="Action" value="urn:errormsg"/>
   <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <send>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://localhost:9765/services/DssService.SOAP11Endpoint/"/>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

canbe pointed to any of your email client.
The given xpath directly pointing to the error message of the SOAP response you have posted in your question.

And to senf the email you can use wso2 esb mail transport in [2].

[1]. http://maharachchi.blogspot.com/2012/09/now-you-can-send-soapfaults-to-fault.html.

[2]. http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/use-mail-transport-esb-convert-soap-message-plain-text-mail

Comment: thanx a lot dharshana ..i have used above property actually i am using two proxys one will do insertion in 2 table another split messages and do insertion in table so when ever error occures in wso2dss i need to execute message but my proxy giving error like this  [2013-03-18 11:59:52,658] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,167]

Comment: but my dss passing error like this [2013-03-18 11:59:52,637] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery} -  ERROR: insert or update on table "tactiondetail" violates foreign key constraint "fktactiondetail_taskid"
  Detail: Key (taskid)=(-18) is not present in table "ttask".
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "tactiondetail" violates foreign key constraint "fktactiondetail_taskid"
  Detail: Key (taskid)=(-18) is not present in table "ttask".
Actually Esb unable to handle this error its givibg directly above error pls help for this

Comment: Where do I need to put this FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT? in InSequence?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code as the faultSequence.

```
<faultSequence>
<log level="custom">
<property name="message" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
</log>
</faultSequence>
```